# AutoCompleteTextView - I'm using autocompletetextview which shows values from API(which returns name and code)

Tags: android

I used model class to get the response and get value from it.

**I want to get ContactId(code) when select a value(name) from AutoComplete drop list?**

**My code**

**OnCreate**

```
edtName.setAdapter(new AutoCustomAdapter());
```

**AdapterClass**

```
private class AutoCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public AutoCustomAdapter() {
            super(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            suggestions = new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return suggestions.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int index) {
            return suggestions.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    JsonParse jp = new JsonParse();
                    if (constraint != null) {
                        // A class that queries a web API, parses the data and
                        // returns an ArrayList<GoEuroGetSet>
                        List<AutoCustomerModel> new_suggestions = jp.getParseJsonWCF(constraint.toString());
                        suggestions.clear();
                        for (int i=0;i<new_suggestions.size();i++) {
                            suggestions.add(new_suggestions.get(i).getName());

                            strClientId = new_suggestions.get(i).getContactId();
                            Log.e("SUGGEST",""+suggestions);
                        }

                        // Now assign the values and count to the FilterResults
                        // object
                        filterResults.values = suggestions;
                        filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
                    }
                    return filterResults;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint,
                                              FilterResults results) {
                    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }
            };
            return myFilter;
        }
    }
```

**JsonParse()**

public class JsonParse {

```
public JsonParse(){}

public List<AutoCustomerModel> getParseJsonWCF(String sName)
{
    List<AutoCustomerModel> ListData = new ArrayList<AutoCustomerModel>();
    try {
        String temp=sName.replace(" ", "%20");
        URL js = new URL("https://xxxxxxxxxURLxxxxxxx"+temp);
        URLConnection jc = js.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jc.getInputStream()));
        String line = reader.readLine();

        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(line);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray(Constant.TAG_contactList);
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject custoList = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            ListData.add(new AutoCustomerModel(custoList.getString("ContactId"),custoList.getString("Name")));
        }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ListData;
}
```

}

By this I'm getting name in dropdown when start to type.

**model class**

```
public class AutoCustomerModel {

    String ContactId, Name;

    public AutoCustomerModel(String contactId, String name) {
        ContactId = contactId;
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getContactId() {
        return ContactId;
    }

    public void setContactId(String contactId) {
        ContactId = contactId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

**What I want is?**

I want to get **Code** when select the **Name** from Drop list

Answer (score 0):

As long as your item of `AutoCompleteTextView` is `AutoCustomerModel`, the adapter you extended can replace with `ArrayAdapter<AutoCustomerModel>`. After doing necessary modification you can get the contactId with `adapter.getItem(position).getContactId()`

Replace `List<String>` with `List<AutoCustomerModel>`. As result, whenever you need any item`s any field, the `suggestions` list is available. (`suggestions.get(position).getContactId()`)

### Extend `ArrayAdapter<AutoCustomerModel>`

snippet for the **necessary modification**

```
class AutoCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AutoCustomerModel> { // String -> AutoCustomerModel
    public AutoCustomAdapter() {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        suggestions = new ArrayList<AutoCustomerModel>(); // String -> AutoCustomerModel
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return suggestions.size();
    }

    @Override
    public AutoCustomerModel  getItem(int index) { // String -> AutoCustomerModel
        return suggestions.get(index);
    }


    // .... the rest of code
}
```